# Rest API delete (not working) for large set of Items in a single list in SharePoint Online(>4000 Items)

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

My scenario is, I have a list called Historic List, where I was trying to delete items(>4000) using Rest API (I was using Batching Size of 100) for deletion for every 2 batches I had set up timeout of 15 sec.
When I start deleting the Items, the task was saying it was deleted but when I check the list it was still Showing Some items were left.

What the best way to find the exact batch size that I need to get the task to finish?

Comment: are you using CSOM in javacsript? post your code plz

Comment: If you found a solution, please share, because there are more people facing a problem like this. I'm driving the SP API from python, trying to delete a large number of data sets. After each 100 elements (all deleted successfully) the connection breaks. Is there some kind of safety mechanism?